# Meaning of おいて in 自分がすごく年おいて感じます

Tags: parsing, reading-comprehension

Such a simple sentence. So much confusion:

> 自分がすごく年**おいて**感じます。
>   I feel so old!

"I feel so old" is not my own translation. I have two problems (at least) with this sentence:

1. What is おいて? I assume it is て形 of おく but that doesn't help me at all.
2. Why 自分? Perhaps if I understand おいて this will become clear.
3. Maybe three problems. I'm not at all sure about the 'verb phrase-て感じる' construction. Could you give a couple of simple examples to help me understand this better?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 「自分{じぶん}がすごく年{とし}おいて感{かん}じます。」

"I feel so old." is a valid translation of that.

> 1. What is おいて? I assume it is て形 of おく but that doesn't help me at all.

The verb used there is 「年老{としお}いる」("to grow old") and not 「おく」("to place, put").

> 2. Why 自分? Perhaps if I understand おいて this will become clear.

「自分{じぶん}」 is very often used to talk about oneself instead of the "actual" personal pronouns.  Recently, I said to a waiter at my favorite restaurant:

「最近{さいきん}、**自分**の家{いえ}よりも、ここで食事{しょくじ}する回数{かいすう}の方{ほう}が多{おお}いかもしれない。」

= "Recently, I probably eat here more often than (I eat) at home."

You would sound very unnatural if you used 「わたし」, 「ボク」, etc. instead of 「自分」 there.

> 3. Maybe three problems. I'm not at all sure about the 'verb phrase-て感じる' construction. Could you give a couple of simple examples to help me understand this better?

I think others will thank you for asking this.  This construct needs some getting used to.

> 「Verb in て-form + Sensory Verbs」

is the structure here.  Being a complete amateur in linguistics or anything language-related, I am not sure if "sensory verbs" is the correct term.  I am referring to verbs such as 「感じる」、「見える」、「聞こえる」, etc.

「年おい**て感じる**」 = "to feel (pretty) old"

「５時間{じかん}しか寝{ね}ていないので、今朝{けさ}は疲{つか}れ**て感じる**。」 = "Because I only slept 5 hours, I feel tired this morning."

「あの人は黒{くろ}い服{ふく}を着{き}るとやせ**て見える**。」 = "S/he looks slimmer in black clothes."

「この部屋{へや}は音{おと}が響{ひび}い**て聞こえる**。」 = "In this room, I feel sounds are echoed."

Answer (score 1):

A few things need to be explained first.

1. 自分 is used to refer to oneself.  Sometimes the meaning is closer to "on my own" or "by myself", but in this case it's a form of saying "I", "me" or "myself".
2. -て感じます is exactly what you'd expect, which is a linked verb and "to feel".
3. すごく is an amplifying word that can mean "very" or "a lot".

So here, the part that doesn't make immediate sense is 年おいて.

Here, おいて is not the て-form of おく, but of 老｛お｝いる, which means "to grow old". Put together with 年 as 年老｛としお｝いる, it's a sort of set phrase that means "to age".

So, putting it back together:

> 自分がすごく年おいて感じます。
>   I feel so old. (lit. [I/myself] feel like I have aged [so much/a lot].)